# How can I authenticate to an HTTP proxy with suds (Python)?

Tags: python, soap, proxy, wsdl, suds

I am trying to hit a web service through suds that requires basic auth through a proxy that also requires basic auth, but I keep getting:

```
suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
```

Does anyone have an example of how to accomplish this?

Comment: I encountered: HTTP 407 - Proxy authentication required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all I needed to do was pass in a proxy={'https':'http://user:pass@proxy:port'} to the Client constructor.